# Cron for all jobs not firing under 4.7.1

Tags: cron, failure, 4.7.1

This was working through 4.6.10 flawlessly on Joomla 3.4.8 and PHP 5.4.x. Under 4.7.1 it is not. Nothing has changed. The cronjob continues to fire in the server and there are no errors in any of the general logs plus CiviCRM logs (../media/civicrm/ConfigAndLogs)
Please advise.

Here is the cronjob:

```
nice -n19 /usr/local/bin/php /home/test/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php -j -s <domain> -u <user> -p <password> -e Job -a execute
```